# ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync freezes

Tags: c#, uwp

This routine freezes in UWP 5.2.2 ver.

How can I solve it?

```
StorageFile file = null;
try
{
    file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("save.xml", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
}
catch (Exception e)
{

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you might be using a insider preview version of Windows 10 or insider preview SDK for Windows 10. Several builds had this behavior that some API calls froze, including `StorageFile` and `MessageDialog` APIs.

You can confirm this is the case if the app works normally when launched without the debugger attached.

To fix this, I recommend updating your PC to a stable version of Windows as well as updating Visual Studio to the latest stable release.